# Better synonym for "actionable"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, management

In managementese, "actionable" means "able to be acted upon".  Unfortunately, its primary meaning is "giving sufficient reason to take legal action" in legalese.  I'm looking for a better alternative to the managementese meaning that doesn't have the unfortunate associations, but still has good Sexy Buzzword Value; help?

Example sentence per request: "This has now become one of our actionable items."

Another, related meaning that's within the range of what I'm looking for is *able to be actively used*.  To illustrate, the best alternative to "actionable" that we've come up with in the original context is *deployable*.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: Why was it not an "actionable item" earlier?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm not looking for a synonym for "actionable item", I'm looking for a synonym for "actionable".  The example sentence is just an example of something "actionable" might appear in, and is *not* an example of how I would actually be using the word.  (I can't give the actual context.  I realize this is a hindrance, but there's nothing to be done about it.)

Comment: @chaos: What I meant is that, like ghoppe's answer, "actionable" seems to be devoid of meaning: *everything* is 'actionable'. I cannot imagine a situation where something wasn't "actionable" and then suddenly became "actionable". You can, at most, say that we're now in a better situation to take action, or that some task has become more crucial/urgent/easier now, etc. If you're looking to not rewrite the sentence into something actually meaningful, you're probably looking for the wrong thing. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I don't think it's really as obscure as all that, but regardless, probably the best results would be obtained from going with the meaning I suggested in comments to ghoppe, of something that *suggests* or *invites* action.  I am just looking to replace the word, not rewrite the sentence, and my requirements are not amenable to suasion on the grounds of treating the English language better, I'm afraid. :)

Comment: It's not meaningless. There are things that we can do something about, and there are things we cannot. X is on hold because we're waiting to hear back from the client. Y, on the other hand, is actionable. Z is not actionable because it's out of our control. X / Y / Z are all "tasks" / "objectives" / etc. We are not actually taking any action on Y, but CAN.

Comment: Is "managementese" even a correct word?

Comment: @Bidella, no, it's a managementese word.

Comment: I once worked for a company whose head was wont to use the expression "critical mass" for this concept. That is, a pet project of his that was now do-able was said to have "reached critical mass".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An improvable item
Augmentable
Progressable

Comment: +1 for [progressable](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she+tossed+herself+off%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22progressable%22&oq=%22progressable%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=21242l22937l1l23522l2l2l0l0l0l0l54l95l2l2l0&gs_l=serp.3...21242l22937l1l23522l2l2l0l0l0l0l54l95l2l2l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=902) - a bit "jargonny", but in OP's context it's fine.

Comment: Yes. I agree with FumbleFingers. It's fine (but not my first choice - which is "actionable" itself - i.e., I believe there is not need for a "better" word).

Comment: @Hexagon Tiling: Well, OP says he's looking for "managementese" terminology. It all sounds a bit sloppy to me though. If you're running a tight ship using Critical Path Analysis, you don't just cast about to see what "actionable/progressable" jobs you have lying around - you get on with the current **critical task**, which the plan has already identified at any given time.

Comment: "Progressable" is the best answer here for my stated purposes.

Comment: Better late than never - glad you could progress on this ;)

Answer (score 4):

I currently say an item is "blocked" or "unblocked".

> How can we unblock X?
>
> What is blocking Y?
>
> We have too many blocking / blocked tasks.

This may work especially well in my field because the term "blocking" means in software development almost what "un-actionable" means in managementese.

Off-topic anecdote: I wondered the same as you, but my motivations were different than yours. I *hate* management speak for the reason @ghoppe stated - they are often an artificial cluster of meaningless words to pretentiously avoid simplicity (ok I said it much stronger). I will never forget when my non-native English speaking friend laughed when she heard, "So now what you are going to want to do here is X" instead of simply "X". Not management speak, but illustrates what lengths we're willing to take just to use more syllables.

[Update]

I just realized a very common phrase in the corporate world that could easily be used for what you need: "In X's court"?

> Is that task in our court?

Means, "is progress of the task currently our responsibility?". If you answer "no", you don't necessarily imply that it's anyone else's responsibility either. So, it doesn't imply whether it's actionable in general or not, but I think in usage this is a very close fit.

Comment: In the third paragraph "blocking" should be replaced with "blocked".

Comment: "Blocking" is used as well in this context

Comment: Maybe but the form of the word that corresponds with _un-actionable_ is _blocked_.

Answer (score 2):

I think, like many "managementese" buzzwords, "actionable item" is pretty much devoid of informational content. I would find a more descriptive word *milestone*, *objective*, *task*, or perhaps *target* and specifically describe the nature of the "item" and why it is "actionable".

> This has now become one of our primary objectives.

or

> This has now become a task that needs to be completed first.

Comment: Treating "actionable item" as a unit doesn't really meet my needs; it's specifically "actionable" that I need to replace.

Comment: @chaos That's my point, "actionable" is devoid of content. What sort of item is **not** actionable? What makes the item actionable? To come up with a replacement, we need to know what makes the item "special."

Comment: Fair enough.  Mix in an implication that the thing described *suggests* or *invites* that action should be taken, then.

Comment: an item you cannot take action on is not actionable. For example "pick up dry cleaning" is not actionable until it's ready for pick-up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there IS a better word. I don't agree that the co-existence of the managerial meaning and the legal meaning is a problem. The two meanings are in different domains, after all. Remember, if we can cope with words that are their own opposites (such as "sanction" - there's a whole thread on this as you all know), we can certaily handle the multiple disparate meanings of "actionable". However, if you INSIST on having a different word, I would go along with "progressable" as given in the answer by mplungjan above. As noted by FumbleFingers, "- a bit "jargonny", but in OP's context it's fine."

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing some ideas out, trying to maintain that management buzzword feel at the cost of grammatical accuracy (agreeing with ghoppe that once a term falls under the purview of management parlance, it starts to bleed meaning until it is an empty husk - c.f. "leverage").

"...has become one of our critical tasks."
"...is now on the critical path."
"...is an agenceable item." 
"...is a scheduleable task."
"...is now prioritary."

Comment: "actionable" contains the idea of option. Most of your suggestions jettison this option. For example, if something is now "actionable", it means we can have it become one of our task, if we choose, but even then it is not necessarily a "critical" task. If all you pay attention to are critical tasks, your company is going to tank. Indeed, take care of the skirmishes, and the battles will take care of themselves:)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *taskable*.  Although it is commonly used to mean "can have tasks assigned to", the meaning of "can be assigned as a task" is not too much of a stretch.

Other possibilities (of varying quality, and not mentioned in answers so far) include *targetable, realizable, resolvable, shovel ready, work ready, assignable, energizable.*

Answer (score 1):

*Implementable*. How about *Effectuate*? How about *encommission*?

*Implementable* is a probable choice. To *implement* means to put into action. *Effectuate* has the same meaning as "bring about", or "bring into effect".

Although *encommision* is not a legitimate word, it has the ring of a buzzword and after all, buzzwords have to be coined by someone some time. The reason I used *commission* as the base word is because when used as a verb it denotes bringing into use.

Comment: You could use *effect* in place of *effectuate* (e.g. she wanted to *effect* changes in government). This should not be confused with *affecting* changes.

Answer (score 0):

We can have some synonyms of Actionable like -

- Prosecutable
- Triable
- Unjust

Some Research : Actionable

- Part of Speech: adjective
- Definition:  litigable
- Outlawed is also similar to actionable.

Comment: The legal meaning is the one I'm trying to avoid. :)

Comment: In which context do you want to use it ?

Comment: Please see the current revision of the question; I've made edits.

Comment: Yes, please do your homework (at the very least, read the question, the whole question, not just the title) before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Adding, as noted in the question, the best alternative we've come up with in the original context, *deployable*.

Answer (score 0):

How about just calling it an "action item?"

It's just as jargon-y, and anybody who would understand "actionable item" will grasp "action item."

I figure this is an extension of my rule not use a long word when a shorter one will do ("use" instead of "utilize").

Comment: The example is just an example; it's specifically the word "actionable" I'm looking to replace, not the phrase "actionable item".  "Actionable item" does not appear in the actual context.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: In my workplaces, an "action item" has always been an item arising from the minutes of a meeting that needs to be acted upon. Not quite the same meaning. *To* be acted on, rather than *able to be* acted on.

Answer (score 0):

First idea:

> This has now become one of our
>   *predicates*.

another:

> This has now become one of our
>   *engagements*.

Comment: Not true. As I noted in an above comment, the idea of "actionable" carries with it the idea of option. Your two ideas jettison this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, this is a difficult term to identify due to the overlap between business and legal meanings. Here's a few tries:

1. 'Follow up'-able / proceed-able — Things in a state that allows action.
2. Do-able / workable — Things capable of being done.

Given your sample sentence, I'd probably go with "workable".

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has mentioned it, I will add *implementable*. It doesn't apply in all contexts that *actionable* does, but where it does apply I think its meaning is very close.